# How to compare data entered by inputText in index.xhtml to a database to see if it exists in JSF and Java class

Tags: java, database, validation, jsf, verify

Ok I've been stuck with this. I have my code set up to accept the fields I need in the xhtml file. The username, password, new password, and confirming the new password. What I can't seem to understand is if I am connecting to the database correctly. I also am not sure how to go about writing the code that will compare the Username and password that is entered in those fields in the xhtml file with the one enter in the database. I then need to confirm that the new password and confirm password are the same and if they are and i click the submit button it will then update the password in the database. Any help would be appreciated

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Change Password</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="mypass">
            <h3>
                Change Password
            </h3> 
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Username"/>
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{passChange.username}" tabindex="1" required="true"
                             requiredMessage="Username is required."/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Old Password"/>
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{passChange.password}" tabindex="1" required="true"
                             requiredMessage="Old Password is required."/>
                <h:outputLabel value="New Password"/>
                <h:inputSecret id="newPassowrd" value="#{passChange.newPassword}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Confirm New Password"/>
                <h:inputSecret id="newPasssword" value="#{passChange.confirmPassword}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action = "PassChanged" actionListener="#" />
             <h:button value="reset" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PassChange implements Serializable{
    private String username = "root@localhost";
    private String password= "root@localhost";
    private String name = "root@localhost";
    private String newPassword;
    private String confirmPassword;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Account [app on APP]";


    public PassChange() {
        this(null, null, "Ashanti Terry", null, null);
        connect();


    }

    public PassChange(String username, String password, String name, String newPassword, String confirmPassword) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }



    public void connect(){
        try {
            String driver = "jbdc:derby:??localhost:1527/Account";
            Class.forName(driver);            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, "root","");                        
        } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);        
        }
        }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNewPassword() {
        return newPassword;

    }

    public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) {
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }


    public String getInput(){
        return "<p style=\"color:green\"> "
        + "Hello, " + name + ", your password has been updated!" + "</p>";
    }
}
```